# Angular: pass complex JSON via routerLink

Tags: json, angular, angular-ui-router, parameter-passing, angular-activatedroute

I'm using Angular 5 and I have this ngFor:

```
<div class="row margin-v-20">
    <my-tile [routerLink]="['/secondPage', item.id, 'item-list']" *ngFor="let item of listaOfItem" [item]="item"></my-tile>
</div>
```

and I need to access from the routed component "secondPage/:id/item-list" to the json object "item" of the list.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/10/passing-complex-data-angular-2-router-nativescript/) explains several ways to achieve this. I recommend to use a service to share the complex data between components ("Using Application Providers" section in the article).

Comment: Application Provider worked flawlessly, very clean and simple, thanks man